# asp:Button onclick not fired when using onclientclick with Jquery validation

Tags: jquery, validation, button, onclick

I'm having trouble getting the asp:button server-side onclick to fire when used with onclientclick.

My button markup is as follows:

```
<asp:Button   ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Next" OnClientClick="return MyFunction();" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" cssClass="submit-right" />
```

With MyFunction as follows:

```
function MyFunction() {
         if ($(".validate-form").valid()) {
            return true;
        } else {

             return false;
         }
    }
```

MyFunction is being called, and the client-side validation is working. But when the form is valid, and MyFunction returns 'true', nothing happens. The page does not postback.

I've tried different variations for the onclientclick e.g.

```
OnClientClick="MyFunction();"
OnClientClick="javascript: return MyFunction();"
OnClientClick="javascript: MyFunction();"
```

I've also tried UseSubmitBehaviour=false, but this just caused the page to postback ignoring the client-side validation.

Any suggestions welcome...

Comment: Not related to question: let's just say that `if (condition) { return true; } else { return false; }` instead of `return condition;` always looks for me like people get salary for code lines count...

Comment: Try posting the generated HTML, this might give some better clues ...

Comment: Have you tried to get rid of outdated inline JS `onclick=""` and to use jQuery's `.on('click'`? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/30eb7Lma/).